# I can't get my texture to apply to my object. Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I created an object in Sketchup, saved as a .dae, imported into blender--and now I am trying to do texturing. It isn't working. The object comes out as a solid color with no image texture seemingly applied.

Note - the Material is included. I've tried it with several different image textures.

This is the blender file . . . https://www.dropbox.com/s/rckymescri9tut4/test1.blend%20-%20Shortcut.lnk?dl=0

The official blender upload:
[image]

Comment: Welcome, Marco Chacon. Use this link to upload .blend files: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your problem is your texture. When i used another texture it worked. Also when rendering an object be sure that you are in object mode.

Comment: Didn't work for me--I tried several different textures. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also uv map it. Make seams and then select all object, press u, and unwrap.

Comment: I'm new to this. How do I UV map it, make seams, etc?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k here you have